# How could integrate dophinscheduler to the system with python evironment?

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

When I am developing an edge system(python environment), for the scheduler part, dolphinscheduler is very suitable for our system. However, dolphinscheduler is mainly coded by java. How could integrate dolphinscheduler to the system with python environment?

Answer (score 0):

For now, Apache DolphinScheduler have a not release python api, maybe you could take a look at [pydolphinscheduler](https://github.com/apache/dolphinscheduler/tree/dev/dolphinscheduler-python/pydolphinscheduler). It help python user define their workflow by code, aka workflow-as-code.

Also have some example in [example](https://github.com/apache/dolphinscheduler/tree/dev/dolphinscheduler-python/pydolphinscheduler/examples) tell us how to use it. I hope that we you looking for. But this api just for workflow-as-code, and it more look like bulk create multiply task in one or more workflow, I am not sure if you want the api create workflow step by step

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `apache/airflow`, it is written with python. Or, can you run dolphinscheduler in other environment, and you can access it with rest API